# Vue.js - repeat an element a specific number of times

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I would like to use Vue.js to repeat an element n times, based on the `num-labels` prop.

```
<label-parent num-labels="4"></label-parent>
```

This is my component:

```
<template>
  <div id="label-parent">
    <div v-for="idx in numLabels">
      {{idx}}
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>;
export default {
  name: "LabelParent",
  props: ['numLabels'],
}
</script>
```

This code only outputs an empty div: `<div id="label-parent"></div>`. What is the correct way of doing this?

Comment: Try `:num-labels="4"`. `num-labels="4"` passes `4` as a string, not as a number.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```js
<label-parent num-labels="4"></label-parent>
```

Passes `4` as a string which won't work with `v-for`.

Pass your argument with `:` to evaluate the expression so you get an actual number which will work with `v-for`.

```js
<label-parent :num-labels="4"></label-parent>
```

BTW:

I highly suggest typing your props.

You can type your props like this:

```js
export default {
    props: {
        numLabels: {
            type: Number, // type of the property
            required: (true|false), // is this prop required or not?
            default: 0 // default value for this prop
        }
    }
}
```

See [Prop Validation](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Prop-Validation)

Comment: Perfect! This solved my issue, and a couple others that had me scratching my head. Thank you very much :)

Answer (score 23):

`v-for` can also take an integer. In this case it will repeat the template that many times.

```
<div v-for="n in 4">{{n}}</div>
```

and you will need to use `v-bind:num-labels="4"` to parse the value as `number`.

[Vue Docs](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html#Range-v-for)

Comment: This does not apply to my scenario. I have clarified my original comment - the number 4 is coming from a component prop.

Comment: it doesn't work because it's parsed as string , and you need to parse the value as number so use `v-bind:num-labels="4"`

Answer (score 2):

As some people notice, this is because you're passing a 4 as string not integer

This should work

```
<label-parent :num-labels="4"></label-parent>
```

And this is the docs reference
[Components Literal-vs-Dynamic](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Literal-vs-Dynamic)